# Is the dangling modifier applicable to an infinitive phrase?

Tags: ellipsis, infinitive-phrases, dangling-modifier

> Incorrect: To see well, **the lights** in this room need to be adjusted. <sup>[niu.edu](https://www.niu.edu/writingtutorial/grammar/dangling-modifiers.shtml)</sup>
>  Correct: To see well, **you** must adjust the lights in this room.

I think the first sentence is a restructuring of :

> The lights in this room need to be adjusted **to see well.**

I don't feel the sentence is misleading or ambiguous.
Usually, in dangling modifier examples, I get the sense that the modifiers is applied in the wrong subject/object. Could you point out where my reasoning derailed?

Comment: I'm not convinced it makes much difference whether you "front" ***to see well*** or not. It's still a "dangling modifier" with no explicit subject.

Comment: Assume a scenario where my friend says he can't see me in a video call. I would say to him "The lights in this room need to be adjusted to see well." I don't think it would confuse him. Are dangling modifiers common in spoken English?

Comment: Native English speakers say things like this often in informal speech. You could argue it isn't really a dangling modifier at all, but merely an example of ellipsis: **[For us] to see well, the lights in this room need to be adjusted.** You are correct, it's not ambiguous, since lights obviously can't see.   However in formal writing, you might want to avoid casual ellipsis like this. There is a difference between spoken /informal English, and formal writing.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for the information, which clarified my confusion.

Comment: @BillyKerr: If we had the full context the identity of the unstated subject would probably be obvious. But *in isolation*, we don't know if it's ***me, you, us, them, anyone,...*** (But it's probably not ***my cat**!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers one of the reasons I got confused was that I was not aware a subject/object was required for an infinitive phrase.

Comment: Obviously it's *not* "required" in any meaningful sense. As @BillyKerr points out, we often say things like this. Actual native speakers don't normally take much notice of what grammarians say. I'm just saying the *label* still applies (and just because we could say ***for [unstated subject]*** is "elided" doesn't change the label of what we've ended up with).

Comment: I mean *required* in the context of formal writing. I change the word *required* to expected :)

Comment: Again, as pointed out by Billy, *in formal writing, you might want to avoid casual ellipsis like this.* Personally, I'd be scathing if someone had the cheek to criticize my writing because I included something like your "non-fronted" version (which as you rightly suspect, is less "noticeable" simply because we've seen enough context to infer the missing subject more easily if it comes later). But I don't have to pass exams set by pedants!

Comment: @FumbleFingers I am a non native speaker. I don't have in depth knowledge of English grammar, and I don't even understand what makes me confused. I try to articulate my doubts by forming some questions like this and the feedback I get from the comments like these is tremendous help to me.

Comment: Well, a "classical" English sentence consists of subject + verb + object. But English is defined by what Anglophones say, not by the principles grammarians might identify "after the fact" by *analyzing* what people say. In practice, there are very few (if *any*) "unbreakable rules" in English. But as has been repeatedly observed - ***First learn the rules. Then break 'em.***

Comment: I have studied English grammar, but didn't study the grammar of my mother tongue. Hence I am not much familiar with the ways I can break the rules. Now I am learning that :)

Comment: As 'the lights' is the subject, the logical meaning is that they need to be adjusted so that _they_ can see well. In practice, no-one would misunderstand the sentence (it's the people in the room who need to see well).